# C++ std::out_of_range error when I try to run the program

Tags: c++, string

Okay so first off, Im pretty new to programming, Ive only read a bit of stuff and have been working on some project Euler problems to kind of wrap my head around concepts and such. However, I got an error message today that I couldn't make any sense of so I thought I would ask here for some help! Any links or advice is appreciated!

Here's the error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'  
what(): basic_string::substr Aborted
```

So any advice you might have would be awesome! If you need to see my code or have questions, ask! Though I''d rather try to understand the problem then find the answer myself! Thanks!

EDIT: Okay since you guys say you would need to see the code here it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int stringtoint(string s_convertee)
{
    int i=0;
    istringstream sin(s_convertee);
    sin >> i;
    return i;
}


int main()
{
string s_testnum = "233456091289474545356";
int n_maxmult = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<s_testnum.length(); i++)
  {
      int n_product = 1;
      for (int j = i; j<(i+4); j++)
      {
          string s_multiplier = s_testnum.substr(j, 1);
          int n_multiplier = stringtoint(s_multiplier);
          n_product *= n_multiplier;
      }
      if (n_product>n_maxmult)
      {
          n_maxmult = n_product;
      }

  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: posting the code would be nice!

Comment: You are trying to access an element, with an index, greater than the size of the string ?

Comment: We're all pretty new to programming, but we've figured out that it has to do with _source code_. Do you have any?

Comment: All the answers here can make well judged guesses on what is wrong but none can point out the exact problem unless you post your source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have already pointed out, in `substr`

**If the position passed is past the end of the string, an out_of_range exception is thrown.**

In your code:

```
for (int j = i; j<(i+4); j++)
```

When `i` is `1` less than `s_testnum.length()` `j` goes past `s_testnum.length()` and when you do, `s_testnum.substr(j, 1);` causes an **out_of_range** exception.

Comment: Would the solution be to change 
for (int i = 0; i<s_testnum.length(); i++) 
to
for (int i = 0; i<(s_testnum.length()-4); i++)?

Comment: @Samuraisoulification: If `i < s_testnum.length()-4` then maximum j will be less than `i+4`, so `j` would never go past the range of `s_testnum`. So Yes, Does that affect the functionality you want to achieve? I leave that for you to ponder upon.

Comment: It made it work at any rate! And helped me find one problem on the for loops I overlooked! thanks for your help man!

Answer (score 5):

From [C++ Reference for substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/),

> If the position passed is past the end
>   of the string, an out_of_range
>   exception is thrown.

So my guess would be your calling `substr` with a first parameter that's greater than the strings length.

---

Since you've posted your code, you can see,

`i` can be a maximum of `s_testnum.length()-1`,

but

`j` goes up to `i+4-1` = `s_testnum.length()+2`.

You then call `substr` with a first parameter of `j` which as said can be longer than the string length. So there's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Please post your code in question. Chances are you did something like:

```
std::string s("foo");
s.substr(5, 1); // The length of the string is 3, 5 is out of bounds
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that the parameter to the `substr` function you called on some string in your code went past the string length. Hence the `std::out_of_range` exception. But it is difficult to say without looking at the code. Also, you can step through the code and debug it yourself using a debugger like gdb/ddd. Just make sure to compile your code with the -g flag on g++.

Comment: difficult? hahaha. Impossible is kinda difficult if you think about it

Comment: @sehe: that was an exercise in understating the obvious! glad someone caught on! :D

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `substr` with invalid parameters - you're trying to get element of the string, that is not there - for example trying to take the 10th char, when the string has only 5.

In your case, this is caused by `substr` - you're trying to get a substring, that is too long for the pointed start position and it "goes out" of the real string.

---

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
```

^^^^ says, that you have an uncaught exception, that is `out_of_range`

```
what(): basic_string::substr Aborted
```

^^^^ This is the text of the exception - note `substr`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to arrange for your debugger to break when an exception is thrown.  Run the program under the debugger, set the appropriate breakpoint, and look at the stack walkback.  (For the record, Ctrl+Alt+E should bring up a dialog box with the exception handling options in Visual Studios; the command `catch throw` activates a breakpoint on an exception under `gdb`.)

Comment: Im not really sure what that is, how to do that? Ive just been kind of clicking the run button on top of my IDE. Im using codeblocks by the way.

Comment: I don't know codeblocks, but before you go any further, you really have to learn how to run the code under a debugger, and use the debugger.